# rxjs error while deploying monorepo angular 8 app to firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, rxjs

I have a monorepo with 2 Angular 8 applications and I'm trying to deploy one of them to firebase using the new `deploy` CLI feature. As I plan to house several applications on this project, I want to get rid of the one in `src` folder so that all my applications are located under the `projects` folder.

The deployment process works great on the application in `src/` folder but fails with the one from the `projects/app` folder.

How to reproduce:

```
ng new project
cd project
ng g application app
ng add @angular/fire
```

And set `defaultProject` to `app` in `angular.json` and fix schematics according to https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2088#issuecomment-529192788

Running

```
ng deploy
```

builds the application just fine (`ng build --prod` doesn't trow error either), but immediately after, the following error occurs:

```
C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
setTimeout(function () { throw err; });                         ^

TypeError: entry.message.split is not a function
at MapSubscriber.IndentLogger._observable._observable.pipe.operators_1.map.entry [as project] (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\logger\indent.js:34:58)
at MapSubscriber._next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:49:35)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at Subject.next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subject.js:60:25)
at IndentLogger.next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\logger\logger.js:79:23)
at SafeSubscriber.job.getChannel.subscribe.entry [as _next] (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\schedule-by-name.js:46:16)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:207:16)
at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:145:22)
at Subscriber._next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:89:26)
at Subscriber.next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at MapSubscriber._next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at FilterSubscriber._next (C:\workspace\jdr\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\filter.js:52:30)
```

Environment:

```
Window 10

@angular: 8.2.10
@angular/fire: 5.2.1
@angular/cli: 8.3.9
rxjs: 6.4.0
```

Comment: I'd say that maybe you need to add rxjs compat as a dependency. Not really sure why, but nrwl monorepo had an issue similar and this fixed. Still, this is coming from your node_modules, so maybe a lib you're using is not compatible. Thought I could maybe shed some light, but I'm not sure. Hope you find a way to have it fixed.

Comment: No, adding rxjs-compat didn't help, but thanks for the suggestion. If it were an incompatible lib, then the build itself would also fail. Plus the only lib I added is @angular/fire.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but it disappeared when I used `ng build` and `firebase deploy`, instead of using `ng deploy`.